# How do I find the primary links config?

Tags: navigation

I'm running Drupal 7, and I am using the Acquia Marina theme. I am having issues with the drop-down menu (using superfish). The menu items with children simply remain expanded.

Every tutorial and user post I've looked at, the Primary Link Configuration table always comes up.

[image: screenshot]

I cannot find this screen, anywhere. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can get to that screen via the 'Administration' page, which you'll find at yourdrupalroot/admin . You'll need to drill down through the subpages there differently depending on your Drupal version; in Drupal 7 it will be under Structure > Menus > Main menu (the renamed version of 'Primary links').

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I went to Structure > Menus > Main menu, this is what I am seeing: http://i.imgur.com/spXFt.png

When I go to Structure > Menus > Main menu>List Links, this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/Ut16M.png

Comment: This is the issue I am trying to resolve, if it helps: http://i.imgur.com/fCOP9.png

The menus drop down automatically and remain collapsed.

Comment: From your first comment, it looks like I've answered your issue as asked (helping you find that screen). But from your second it looks like you have another issue - however I'm not clear what it is! I recommend you create another question describing it fully and point me to it in these comments :)